# Factorisation and Finding number of integral non negative solutions of equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, factoring

[image]

Please help in solving Q9  of above image. 
I think I must factor the expression or express it as sum of squares. But I am not able to. Please help. Thank you in advance.

In above image ,in last line, it is "all of" rather than "cell of"

Comment: Write the equation as $x^2- 2xy+ y^2- 4yz+ 4z^2- 2x- 2y+ 4z+ 5= 9$.

Comment: @user247327  and then what??

Comment: Ohh  thank you got it